# how to remove %20 in the url in php

Tags: php

Current Code:

```
<?php

include('conn.php');
$sql = mysql_query("select min(news_id) 'min' from news");
$res = mysql_fetch_array($sql);
$qry=mysql_query("select * from news order by date(post_date) desc,priority desc ");
while($row1=mysql_fetch_array($qry)) {
    <p class='news_title'><a href='newsdetail.php?id=".urldecode($row1['news_heading'])."'>{$row1['news_heading']}</a></p>
}

?>
```

As I am passing the heading to the next page ...

The url in the next page is displaying like this

> newsdetail.php?id=In%20front%20%20of%20the%20houses

I need to display like this:

> newsdetail.php?id=In front of the houses

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/de/function.urldecode.php

Comment: remove space from url...

Comment: `urldecode` - http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php

Comment: It would be best not to urldecode the `href` property, since this is what the browser uses, and only urldecode the visible text of the link.

Comment: Nevermind, I misread the problem. The browser is what is adding the url encoding, and there is nothing you can do about it, so get over it.

Answer (score 8):

You can use `urldecode` to convert the URL string.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php

```
echo urldecode('newsdetail.php?id=In%20front%20%20of%20the%20houses');
```

will produce:

```
newsdetail.php?id=In front of the houses
```

Comment: <a href='newsdetail.php?id=".urldecode($row1['news_heading'])."'>{$row1['news_heading']}</a>  i am passing like this but still not getting

Comment: i am geeting them dynamically fro db

Comment: Not sure why this is down voted when this is correct answer.

Answer (score 3):

You can't have spaces or special characters in the URL. 
If you try to put them in, then the browser will put %20 for spaces.

for clean url please replace the space or special charcters with hypen(-)

```
function cleanURL($textURL) {
  $URL = strtolower(preg_replace( array('/[^a-z0-9\- ]/i', '/[ \-]+/'), array('', '-'), $textURL));
            return $URL;
     }



while($row1=mysql_fetch_array($qry)) {
        <p class='news_title'><a href='newsdetail.php?id=".cleanURL($row1['news_heading'])."'>{$row1['news_heading']}</a></p>
    }
```

The output will be

newsdetail.php?id=In-front-of-the-houses

Think so this will help you

Comment: str_replace('%20', ' ', $url);

Answer (score 2):

You can't have raw spaces in the URL. If you try to put them in, then the browser will error correct and escape them for you.

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
$url = str_replace(' ', '-', strtolower($news_heading));
```

replace the space of this function